# On the integer solutions of $aX^2+bY^2=cZ^2+q$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

In [this article in AoPS](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3046h1390537_number_representation_using_polynomials) the author gives a parametric solution to

$$
\begin{equation}
aX^2+bY^2=cZ^2+q \tag 1
\end{equation}
$$

in terms of the solutions to the equation

$$ax^2+by^2=cz^2 \tag 2$$ as

$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{align}
X=\frac{x}{2}(ck^2-as^2-bp^2+q)+s \\
Y=\frac{y}{2}(ck^2-as^2-bp^2+q)+p \\
Z=\frac{z}{2}(ck^2-as^2-bp^2+q)+k
\end{align}
\end{cases} \tag 3
$$

where $s,p,k$ are solutions of the linear diophantine equation

$$axs+byp-czk=1. \tag 4$$

**Question:** Can we generate all solutions of $(1)$ from ***all*** solutions of Eqn. $(2)$ or is just a single particular solution of $(2)$ sufficient?

As an example, I was trying to solve $X^2 + 3Y^2 = Z^2 + 144832$.
The equation $x^2 + 3y^2 = z^2$ has particular solutions $(1,0,1), (1,1,2), \cdots$.

Are the solutions $(X,Y,Z)$ generated from $(1,0,1)$ equivalent to the solutions generated from $(1,1,2)$?

Comment: Well, the original author gives no derivation, no commentary, and no context... so I'd take the entire post with a big grain of salt. If nothing else, there's no guarantee that $ck^2-as^2-bp^2$ has the same parity as $q$, yet they happily divide by $2$, nonetheless claiming or at least implying integer solutions. Maybe it works great if you can pick and choose your $s,p,k$, but I have no clue if this is useful or just *looks* good but lacks grounding in reality.

Comment: Having said that, doing some mental math with small numbers suggests that you'll get results if you can pick and choose your values of $(s,p,k)$. Since you'll have different choices for those depending on the choice of solution $(x,y,z)$, it seems reasonable that you only need to make one of the choices once. That is, you might get the same solutions using $(x,y,z)=(1,0,1)$ and some $s,p,k$ as by using $(x,y,z)=(1,1,2)$ and a different $s', p', k'$. But... you might not. The original gives no indication; you may have to just play around and find out!

Comment: One way to get all integer triples  for $x^2 + 3 y^2 = z^2 + 144832$ is to take any value for $y$  and write $x^2 - z^2 = 144832 - 3 y^2.$   As  the right hand side is  not double an odd number, we get the finite set of $x,z$  pairs by factoring   $uv = 144832 - 3 y^2,$  with $u \equiv v \pmod 2,$ including positive or negative $u,v$ then $x = \frac{u+v}{2}$ and  $z = \frac{u-v}{2}$

Comment: @WillJagy: Followup question on your comment above. You mention *all* triples and *any value for $y$*. Did you mean all triples for the specific chosen $y$ satisfying the condition? Surely, there may be multiple values of $y$ that satisfy the condition that occur in satisfying triples?

Comment: **Every**  integer $y$  gives satisfying triples.  Try a few.  For even $y, \; \;$  write  $N =144832 - 3 y^2.$  Factor $N,$  find all  (positive and negative)  divisors $u$    such that both $u$ and $v = \frac{N}{u}$  are even.    For odd $y,$   analogous  although both $u,v$  will be odd  automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is output as I indicAted,  using  $u,v$   positive  only. One may then negate $x$ or $z$  or both...

$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$

```
Sat 29 Oct 2022 11:56:31 AM PDT

 x: 36209 y: 0 z: -36207        u:  2  v: 72416 
 x: 18106 y: 0 z: -18102        u:  4  v: 36208 
 x: 9056 y: 0 z: -9048        u:  8  v: 18104 
 x: 4534 y: 0 z: -4518        u:  16  v: 9052 
 x: 2279 y: 0 z: -2247        u:  32  v: 4526 
 x: 1199 y: 0 z: -1137        u:  62  v: 2336 
 x: 646 y: 0 z: -522        u:  124  v: 1168 
 x: 569 y: 0 z: -423        u:  146  v: 992 
 x: 416 y: 0 z: -168        u:  248  v: 584 
 x: 394 y: 0 z: -102        u:  292  v: 496 
 x: 394 y: 0 z: 102        u:  496  v: 292 
 x: 416 y: 0 z: 168        u:  584  v: 248 
 x: 569 y: 0 z: 423        u:  992  v: 146 
 x: 646 y: 0 z: 522        u:  1168  v: 124 
 x: 1199 y: 0 z: 1137        u:  2336  v: 62 
 x: 2279 y: 0 z: 2247        u:  4526  v: 32 
 x: 4534 y: 0 z: 4518        u:  9052  v: 16 
 x: 9056 y: 0 z: 9048        u:  18104  v: 8 
 x: 18106 y: 0 z: 18102        u:  36208  v: 4 
 x: 36209 y: 0 z: 36207        u:  72416  v: 2 

 x: 72415 y: 1 z: -72414        u:  1  v: 144829 
 x: 72415 y: 1 z: 72414        u:  144829  v: 1 

 x: 36206 y: 2 z: -36204        u:  2  v: 72410 
 x: 7246 y: 2 z: -7236        u:  10  v: 14482 
 x: 2798 y: 2 z: -2772        u:  26  v: 5570 
 x: 622 y: 2 z: -492        u:  130  v: 1114 
 x: 622 y: 2 z: 492        u:  1114  v: 130 
 x: 2798 y: 2 z: 2772        u:  5570  v: 26 
 x: 7246 y: 2 z: 7236        u:  14482  v: 10 
 x: 36206 y: 2 z: 36204        u:  72410  v: 2 

 x: 72403 y: 3 z: -72402        u:  1  v: 144805 
 x: 14483 y: 3 z: -14478        u:  5  v: 28961 
 x: 14483 y: 3 z: 14478        u:  28961  v: 5 
 x: 72403 y: 3 z: 72402        u:  144805  v: 1 

 x: 36197 y: 4 z: -36195        u:  2  v: 72392 
 x: 18100 y: 4 z: -18096        u:  4  v: 36196 
 x: 9053 y: 4 z: -9045        u:  8  v: 18098 
 x: 9053 y: 4 z: 9045        u:  18098  v: 8 
 x: 18100 y: 4 z: 18096        u:  36196  v: 4 
 x: 36197 y: 4 z: 36195        u:  72392  v: 2 

 x: 72379 y: 5 z: -72378        u:  1  v: 144757 
 x: 72379 y: 5 z: 72378        u:  144757  v: 1
```

$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$

middle of the program

```
for(y = 0;  y <= 5; ++y ){
cout << endl;
           set<mpz_class>  div = mp_Divisors(  144832 - 3 * y * y); 
   set<mpz_class>::iterator iter;
   for(iter = div.begin(); iter != div.end(); ++iter)
   {
      u = *iter;
      v = (  144832 - 3 * y * y)  / u;
      if ( (u-v) % 2 == 0    )
      {
         x = (u+v)/ 2;
         z = (u-v)/ 2;
         cout << " x: " << x << " y: "  << y << " z: "  << z << "        u:  "  << u  << "  v: " << v <<" "  << endl;
       }  // even

   }  // for iter


}  // for y
```

$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$

$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$

Comment: +1 for C++ code.